# I locked and unlocked hidden files and now computer will not get to GUI - is there a directory or file I can modify?

Tags: login

The question for this is difficult to determine. Simply, using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, been modified by someone else to 'harden' the OS, though I do not know what was done. 32-bit OS; single arm board. Computer won't get to GUI after restarting.

I was locking "hidden files" on the home folder that were part of the file system. I used "sudo chmod 700 file" and "sudo chown root:root file". After doing this to all the hidden files and directories, first, I noticed that my terminal's 'host@server' text characters had gotten large and white. But the main thing was that when I restarted the computer, I got a login screen. I never get a log in screen except when the OS was first being installed. I never login.

I'm using orangpiplus2e 16GB micro-sd. I put it in another computer and unlocked all the locked files and directories. When I put it back in the sbc computer, it did start processing this time, and said 'starting kernel', but then I got a blank screen and then after a few minutes, the login screen again. I have tried the login 25 times, but it doesn't work. I am using my hostname and my desktop password. Also, it says "incorrect login - 60 seconds timed out". But, it is less than 60 seconds and sometimes refreshes in 30 seconds.

Is there a file that needs modifying so that the computer goes back to the OS starting normally whereby I get my GUI screen instead of a login screen?

Comment: Can you access tty1 pressing ctrl+alt+f1?

Comment: It actually says "tty1" at the top above the login info

Comment: AFAIK nothing in your home folder should be `root:root` - and certain things being so (in particular, the `.Xauthority` file) **will** prevent startup of your user's graphical X session (aka a "login loop")

Comment: Before I restarted the computer, I changed permissions and ownershop for .Xauthority and a few other files and directories, though the terminal letters were still white and larger. When modifying permissions for folders to lock them, is it necessary to use "sudo chown user@server file" or just do 'sudo chmod 700 file"? Thx. I don't know what I can do the .Xauthority file if the permissions and ownership were all that I changed and then removed.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the purpose of this, what do you mean by "locking"?

Comment: Purpose of locking them is such that if someone else uses my computer they can not change the files or delete them maliciously. I noticed that there were thumbnails on the file system I didn't know were there and I decided to lock all files and folders after that to keep things private. Locking is changing permissions to 700 and only i have the sudo password.

Comment: You have successfully broken your account, as it seems from your description that a significant number of the user's files and directories are now accessible only by the root user. Best thing at this point is probably to create a new user account and use that instead. Oh, and don't "lock" these new files.

Comment: Well, that may be, but they are unlocked now and the permissions changed.

Comment: You only needed to change the permissions of the /home/youruser folder to prevent access to other users.

Comment: How do you know what the original permissions were if you changed them all to 0700?

Comment: Uh, "_if someone else uses my computer they can not change the files or delete them_". Provided you give them a different login account, and don't give them the root password or sudo access, this is already the case.

Comment: GC: yes, but not being familiar with it I was going by instructions from a video online; I was wondering if the chown was necessary. R: no, the files were not locked before so they didn't need the password.

Comment: @steeldriver: I accidentally deleted the .Xauthority file a few weeks ago, but it did not seem to cause a problem, until maybe now. I had read that the system would automatically create a new one for itself, but it never did. How can I manually create one? Maybe the hardest thing about this is that I need to create it on one computer for a different computer. I am reading about it now, but don't know how generic they can be. Thx.

Comment: @veagle88 it should be created automatically but only when you successfully start an X session. Is your home *directory* now owned and writeable by you?

Comment: @steeldriver: I think so, but on a different computer.

Comment: @steeldriver: I see 2 home folders. The one I think is important has: directories: .gphoto,.gvfs, .kde, .local, .mozilla, .nano, .pki, .ssh, .thumbnails, .thunderbird; files: .ICEauthority, .profile, .sudo_as_admin_successful, .wget-hsts, .Xsession-errors, .bash_history, .hx, .viminfo. The "other" home folder has things like ".cache" ".config", others.......

Comment: Since the GUI will not boot, I don't seem to be able to do anything. I'm guessing that if I download ubuntu 16.04 LTS, that maybe I can just copy the .Xauthority file from there and add it to my hidden files. But, I'm not 100% sure this is the problem.